# Problem with encoding csv file to UTF-8 format (diacritics shows as Ø)

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

Im trying to convert CSV rows with my tool to string - its used for registration of multiple users - but every time I write firstname/lastname with diacritics (ěščřž) in my CSV file and use my tool to convert each row to string, these characters shows instead as strange character Ø

I tried utf8_encode($item) and mb_convert_encoding($item, 'UTF-8'). It didnt work at all. Iconv returns "Detected an illegal character in input string"

```
{
array_walk_recursive($row, function(&$item) {

    //Convert encoding to UTF-8 if its not UTF-8
    if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
        $item = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($item), 'utf-8', $item);
    }
});

return $row;
}
```

mb_detect_encoding returns FALSE on these (like its not able to determine encoding) - but only when used diacritics like "Příjmení". If i write "Prijmeni" then mb_detect_encoding successfully detect encoding as UTF-8.

When i input rows "Řádek;Příjmení;Příjmení;Test;mail@mail.com" I expect output array

```
[0] => "Řádek"
[1] => "Příjmení"
[2] => "Příjmení"
[3] => "Test"
[4] => "mail@mail.com"
```

But with code i described above, it returns array

```
[0] => "Øádek"
[1] => "PØíjmení"
[2] => "PØíjmení"
[3] => "Test"
[4] => "mail@mail.com"
```

Im reading CSV file as splFileObject and encoding is UTF-8. If I insert it to db its same as I described (Øádek ; Pøíjmení) (but thats not mandatory, i get data from CSV, not database,)

Thanks for any idea how to fix this

Comment: I suspect you're using `utf8_encode()` and `mb_detect_encoding()` without actually knowing their purpose. Auto-detecting the encoding of a file programmatically is basically impossible, that explains why PHP doesn't have a builtin function.

Comment: If you don't know the character encoding of your user's text, you have already lost data. Maybe you can go upstream/back in time to a point before it was lost and carry it on down.

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution to help you to fix your problem.

```
<?php

function getRightData($fullstring)
{
  $arrayExploded = explode(';', $fullstring);
  $arrayString = [];

  foreach($arrayExploded AS $key => $string){

    $utf8_chars = explode(' ', 'À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö');
    $utf8_double_encoded = array();
    foreach($utf8_chars as $utf8_char)
    {
      $utf8_double_encoded[] = utf8_encode(utf8_encode($utf8_char));
    }
    $arrayString[$key] = str_replace($utf8_double_encoded, $utf8_chars, $string);
  }

  return $arrayString;
}

print_r(getRightData('Řádek;Příjmení;Příjmení;Test;mail@mail.com'));
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Řádek
    [1] => Příjmení
    [2] => Příjmení
    [3] => Test
    [4] => mail@mail.com
)
```